Issue with STP putting links to Blocking between multiple linux hosts without physical switches in between
Have the following network topology between Linux (RHEL 8.6) hosts, no physical network appliances between the hosts:

bridge link show command output on Host A:
...
33: br0-1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
33: br0-1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0
34: br1-1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br1 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
34: br1-1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br1
...
36: br0-2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
36: br0-2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0
37: br1-2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br1 state blocking priority 32 cost 100
37: br1-2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br1
...
39: br0-3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
39: br0-3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0
40: br1-3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br1 state blocking priority 32 cost 100
40: br1-3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br1


The SRIOV VFs are separated by VLANs, those SRIOV VFs has unique MAC addresses (except 2 on the Host A side which shares the same MAC address with the bridges)
No bridge setup on Host B/C/D as those SRIOV VFs are normal Linux network interfaces, they have IP addresses within the same subnet as the connected bridge on Host A.
When physically disconnecting Host B from Host A, the blocking between Host A and Host C (SRIOV VF1) become Forwarding. Subsequently, when physically disconnecting Host C from Host A, the blocking between Host A and Host D (SRIOV VF1) become Forwarding.
It's really random which of the VF0/VF1 links become blocking/forwarding between Host A and Host C/D, after reboot it could be links between VF0 instead of VF1 that become blocking between Host A and Host C/D (and VF1 link become forwarding)
When disabling the STP using nmcli on the bridges, they all become forwarding for a short while before the node become inaccessible with console output of:

bnxt_en <PCI address> br0-1: TX timeout detected, starting reset!
bnxt_en <PCI address> br1-3: TX timeout detected, starting reset!
bnxt_en <PCI address> br0-2: TX timeout detected, starting reset!
...

So seems there is really loop introduced when disabling the STP.
Then question is how can we fix it witout disabling STP?

Seems I understand the issue now:
The issue resides only on Host A and has nothing to do with host B/C/D
There is important detail that SRIOV VFs within same PF shares same STP domain, so STP would detect the loop between br0 and br1, see below pic:

So need to redesign to eliminate the loop:

one bridge instead of 2 bridges
one SRIOV VF instead of 2 on each NIC port
change in application so both traffic types go to br0


